# CoreData: Using transient properties with read-only persistent store

Tags: ios, core-data, readonly, transient, nspersistentstore

Dealing with managed objects (`NSManagedObject`) from `read-only` persistent store I was trying to use transient properties to store some temporary values. Took in account transient properties were not saved to persistent store I supposed there was nothing wrong to use them for cache purposes. But as it turned out you cannot write data even in transient properties of managed objects from `read-only` store. During `NSManagedContext`'s save operation i got this error

> "Cannot update objects into a read only store"

(I'm sure only transient properties were changed.)

Why is that? Can it be considered as a `NSManagedObjectContext`'s bug? Thanks for sharing your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. A *read only* store cannot be modified. Not even in the managed object context (in memory). That is the meaning of "read only". Hardly a bug.

The solution is fairly simple. Create a second in-memory persistent store and integrate it into your managed object model via **Configurations**. Keep track of your transient property via this store. Perhaps you have to create a "wrapper" entity and link it to the read-only store via a relationship.

Despite the effort of creating a more complicated model setup, I think this is a feasible solution because once you have done this setup you can basically forget about it.

Comment: You have a point. I just thought that in this case save operation should be painless since it's not an attempt to write data to persistent store.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your own property in entity class:

```
@interface DBExample : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *userInfo;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation DBExample

@synthesize userInfo = _userInfo;

@end
```

And by the way, why are you saving context with attached read-only persistent store?

Comment: Thank you for a simple solution. Using such a custom property even better for my purposes, because I keep model graph clean of temp attributes. Besides I don't need any undo management which transient properties are basically intended for.
As far as your question. My persistent store coordinator contains two persistent stores with the same data structures. One of them (default data set) is read-only.

Comment: The only thing I'd like to add is if you define custom instance variables or properties like that "you should clean up these variables in didTurnIntoFault rather than dealloc". (From NSManagedObject documentation.)